# Isuzu KB won't Start after an Hour

Tags: starting, diesel, truck, jump-start, isuzu

I parked my Isuzu KB Fleetside diesel bakkie (truck).  An hour later, I tried to start it, but the engine wouldn't start.

It turns on, but the starter does not crank. The lights turn on, but the indicator does not turn on. The radio is not working. Lights and hazards work fine. Indicators and the radio are not turning on.

I had to jump start it in order to get it home.

**What could be the remedy?**

Comment: Battery is dead.

Comment: Is the radio working once you get it going?

Comment: What year is your vehicle?

Comment: If the lights weaken a lot or even dim completely when you try to start it, the battery is dead. It's still doing something, but it can't hold enough capacity anymore to power the starter motor.